# How to create conditional breakpoint with std::string

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, conditional-breakpoint

Suppose I have this function:

```
std::string Func1(std::string myString)
{
   //do some string processing 
   std::string newString = Func2(myString)
   return newString;  
}
```

How do I set a conditional break when `newString` has a specific value?  (without changing the source)

Setting the condition  `newString == "my value"` didn't work. The breakpoints were disabled with an error `overloaded operator not found`.

Comment: I don't know if this is the intention, but your code is broken. Func1 returns void, yet you return a std::string. Func2 is not shown, but it probably doesn't return a std::string, furthermore you're using the == (equals) operator rather than = (assignment).

Comment: bad example on my side, fixed   but the point was to illustrate the problem of getting a conditional breakpoints with std::string to work

Comment: Related for GDB: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801112/gdb-conditional-breakpoint-on-arbitrary-types-such-as-c-stdstring-equality

Comment: Check answers down the page for other versions of Visual Studio. Kudos to @Rai for VS 2017+. An actual simple implementation to remember.

Comment: Is anyone know how to compare int values?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Some searching has failed to turn up any way to do this.  Suggested alternatives are to put the test in your code and add a standard breakpoint:

```
if (myStr == "xyz")
{
    // Set breakpoint here
}
```

Or to build up your test from individual character comparisons.  Even looking at individual characters in the string is a bit dicey; in Visual Studio 2005 I had to dig down into the member variables like

```
myStr._Bx._Buf[0] == 'x' && myStr._Bx._Buf[1] == 'y' && myStr._Bx._Buf[2] == 'z'
```

Neither of these approaches is very satisfactory.  We should have better access to a ubiquitous feature of the Standard Library.

Comment: +1.  I was just writing a similar answer.  The only way I know of to do this is to peek inside the implementation.  Note that for std::string, this can get pretty complicated because of the short string optimization.

Comment: This has the problem that `myStr._Bx._Buf` is only valid when `myStr._Mysize < _BUF_SIZE`. Otherwise you need to use `myStr._Bx._Ptr`

Comment: This answer is no longer relevant for newer Visual Studio. `strcmp(myStr._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr, "xyz") == 0` just works

Answer (score 98):

There is a much easier way in Visual Studio 2010/2012.

To accomplish what you are looking for in ANSI use this:

```
strcmp(newString._Bx._Ptr,"my value")==0
```

And in unicode (if newString were unicode) use this:

```
wcscmp(newString._Bx._Ptr, L"my value")==0
```

There are more things you can do than just a compare, you can read more about it here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/07/07/new-visual-studio-debugger-2010-feature-for-c-c-developers-using-string-functions-in-conditional-breakpoints.aspx

Comment: I like this answer, it worked for me (with some exceptions where the memory was not accessable).

Comment: As other comments have suggested, accessing `newString._Bx._Ptr` may not work for short strings. In my case I got "Attempted to read or write protected memory". For short strings (16 characters or less?), `newString._Bx._Buf` seems to hold the characters.

Comment: Is this supposed to work in VS2015 as well? Because it doesn't seem to work on my end...

Comment: I don't know about VS, but for gdb you can write `strcmp(newString.c_str(), "my_value") == 0`. Might need more calculation internaly, but is imho easier to remember.

Comment: @Jounathaen Doesn't work in VS unfortunately: "This expression has side effects and will not be evaluated."

Comment: Try your_string._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf . Works in VS2015.

Comment: if one does `strcmp(m_object->m_str, "helloworld") == 0` and m_object or m_str is null this is inconvenient. any workarounds for this? noticed that `m_object && m_object->m_str && strcmp(...)` does not work

Comment: `newString.c_str()` does not work in MSVC 2019 (Tested in version 16.9.10) as it complains: "This expression has side effects and will not be evaluated.". (It complains despite c_str() function is  const.)

Answer (score 64):

In  VS2017, I was able to set the condition as:

```
strcmp(&newString[0], "my value") == 0
```

Comment: Works in VS2019 too, and is much more obvious and readable and easier to remember than all the other answers.

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't work for me in VS2019 (it complains about _Bx), but this does.

Comment: VS2022 also doesn't like `._Bx` at least with basic strings

Comment: This is nice and simple without painful syntax and just works regardless of short strings or long strings.  This should be the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 23):

In VS2017 you can do

```
strcmp(newString._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf,"myvalue")==0
```

Comment: It actually depends on the Windows SDK you are using. I am using 10.1.15068 with Visual Studio 2015 and this works, whereas string._Bx._Buf or string._Bx._Ptr do not.

Comment: `strstr(processName._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr,"scr")!=0` worked for me. I was trying to find a process which has scr in its name (screen savers have .scr extention).

Answer (score 8):

While I've had to work around this using something similar to Brad's answer (plus using [DebugBreak()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to break right from the code), sometimes editing/recompiling/re-running a bit of code is either too time consuming or just plain impossible.

Luckily, it's apparently possible to spelunk into the actual members of the std::string class.  One way is mentioned [here](http://www.suodenjoki.dk/us/archive/2010/conditional-breakpoint.htm) -- and though he calls out VS2010 specifically, you can still access individual chars manually in earlier versions.  So if you're using 2010, you can just use the nice `strcmp()` functions and the like ([more info)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/07/07/new-visual-studio-debugger-2010-feature-for-c-c-developers-using-string-functions-in-conditional-breakpoints.aspx), but if you're like me and still have 2008 or earlier, you can come up with a raggedy, terrible, but functional alternative by setting a breakpoint conditional something like:

```
strVar._Bx._Ptr[0] == 'a' && strVar._Bx._Ptr[1] == 'b' &&
   strVar._Bx._Ptr[2] == 'c'
```

to break if the first three characters in strVar are "abc".  You can keep going with additional chars, of course.  Ugly.. but it's saved me a little time just now.

Answer (score 8):

VS2012:

I just used the condition below because `newString._Bx._Ptr` [( as in OBWANDO's answer )](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15196867/4863783) referenced illegal memory

```
strcmp( newString._Bx._Buf, "my value")==0
```

and it worked...

Answer (score 3):

[@OBWANDO (almost) has the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15196867/7403199), but as multiple comments rightly point out, the actual buffer depends on the string size; I see 16 to be the threshold. Prepending a size check to the strcmp on the appropriate buffer works.

```
newString._Mysize < 16 && strcmp(newString._Bx._Buf, "test value") == 0
```

or

```
newString._Mysize >= 16 && strcmp(newString._Bx._Ptr, "ultra super long test value") == 0
```

Comment: This is a consequence of the small buffer optimization. High level overview here https://blogs.msmvps.com/gdicanio/2016/11/17/the-small-string-optimization/. More in depth here https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2014/04/14/common-optimizations/

Comment: Yes that's the correct solution. As noted, the small string optimization does not allocate memory if the string length is less than 16

Answer (score 2):

Tried to use `strcmp` in `gdb8.1` under `ubuntu18.04`, but it doesn't work:

```
(ins)(gdb) p strcmp("a", "b")
$20 = (int (*)(const char *, const char *)) 0x7ffff5179d60 <__strcmp_ssse3>
```

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51935047/4922642), `strcmp`, is a special [IFUNC](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/GNU_IFUNC), one can setup condition like this:

```
condition 1 __strcmp_ssse3(camera->_name.c_str(), "ping")==0
```

It's pretty ugly, don't want to do it the second time.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10803131/4922642) gives a much better solution, it use [std::string::compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) :

```
condition 1 camera->_name.compare("ping") == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

In VS2015 you can do

```
newstring[0]=='x' && newString[1]=='y' && newString[2]=='z'
```

Answer (score 1):

Comparing string works better than comparing characters

```
strcmp(name._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf, "foo")==0
```

This works, but is very inconvenient to use and error prone.

```
name._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf[0] == 'f' && 
name._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf[1] == '0' && 
name._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf[2] == '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert it into a c string using `c_str()` like so:

`$_streq(myStr.c_str(), "foo")`

Answer (score 0):

To set a conditional breakpoint in std::string you need to set it on real internal members of std::string. What you see on watch window is simplified.

You can display real structure of a variable in the watch window by using `,!` suffix. In your example:

```
newString,!
```

**For MSVC 2015 – 2019 you can use:**

For string that were never longer than 15 characters:

```
(newString._Mypair._Myval2._Myres < 16) ?
    strcmp(newString._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf, "short") == 0 : 
    false
```

For (even historically) longer strings:

```
(newString._Mypair._Myval2._Myres < 16) ? false : 
     strcmp(newString._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr, "My_test_str_value_longer_than_16_chars") == 0
```

**Beware:**

- The variable name is written twice in each condition!
- You need whole expression on single line. Use the copy-paste versions bellow.

Universal condition needs to put the test value twice and variable name three times:

```
(newString._Mypair._Myval2._Myres < 16) ? 
    strcmp(newString._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf, "My_test_string") == 0 : 
    strcmp(newString._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr, "My_test_string") == 0
```

Notes: use `wcscmp` instead of `strcmp` if you are working with `std::wstring`.

Find more info on small string optimization in C++ https://vorbrodt.blog/2019/03/30/sso-of-stdstring/ includes sample code to find size of string's internal buffer.

**All std:string and std::wstring single line versions for your copy paste convenience:**

```
(newString._Mypair._Myval2._Myres < 16) ? strcmp(newString._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf, "short") == 0 : false

(newString._Mypair._Myval2._Myres < 16) ? false : strcmp(newString._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr, "My_test_str_value_longer_than_16_chars") == 0

(newString._Mypair._Myval2._Myres < 16) ? strcmp(newString._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf, "My_test_string") == 0 : strcmp(newString._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr, "My_test_string") == 0


(newString._Mypair._Myval2._Myres < 16) ? wcscmp(newString._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf, L"short") == 0 : false

(newString._Mypair._Myval2._Myres < 16) ? false : wcscmp(newString._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr, L"My_test_str_value_longer_than_16_chars") == 0

(newString._Mypair._Myval2._Myres < 16) ? wcscmp(newString._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf, L"My_test_string") == 0 : wcscmp(newString._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr, L"My_test_string") == 0
```

**All above copy/paste samples tested on MSVC version 16.9.10 and program for Windows 10.**