# How to set conditional breakpoint based on string comparison in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints, string-comparison, conditional-breakpoint

This is something I have tried from time to time over the years and never quite succeeded. I just want to set a conditional break point for Visual C++ 2012 based on string equality. The variable I want to test is

```
string test;
```

I tried

```
test == "foo"
=> The breakpoint cannot be set. no operator "==" matches these operands

test == string("foo")
=> The breakpoint cannot be set. no operator "==" matches these operands

test.compare("foo") == 0
=> The breakpoint cannot be set. This expression has side effects and will not be evaluated.

strcmp(test.c_str(), "foo") == 0
=> The breakpoint cannot be set. This expression has side effects and will not be evaluated.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For use in Visual Studio, this has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740858/how-to-create-conditional-breakpoint-with-stdstring).  In particular, the string provided in OBWANDO's answer can be used to set the break point condition.  Note, however, that it is a bit klugy.  You will receive a warning message when the breakpoint is hit even though the debugger has stopped.  It doesn't appear to cause any harm.

Comment: Yes, that post answers my question and OBWANDO's solution also works perfectly for me. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score -5):

You can use the following portable and simple way:

```
if (!test.compare("foo")) {
    int dummy = 0; // any statement, put breakpoint here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am searching for a way to set a breakpoint condition without modifying source code.

Comment: you can always try test[0] == ''