# Can I add support for conditional breakpoints for custom objects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Microsoft visual studio 2010 allows to set up a conditional breakpoint. Language used to define breakpoint condition is not really explained, but seems to follow C++ syntax.

For complicated objects, [such as `std::string` or `QString`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15196867/607407), it simply doesn't work.

You cannot obviously call member methods such as `.c_str` on those objects, but it seems that you can call C functions such as `strcmp`. This brings me to the question:

Can I define my own C-like functions for comparing custom objects that will be accessible with conditional breakpoints. Example:

```
// Function to compare QString with const char*
bool q_string_equals(const QString& qstr, const char* str) {
    // some code, probably pretty complicated if we really wanna avoid calling member fns
}
```

Then use it like:

[image: image description]

The need to recompile whole project to add `if` based "breakpoint" is really annoying.