# memset() does not work when called in GDB thru Python APIs

Tags: gdb, ctypes, gdb-python

I'm trying to memset the data at some address in a gdb session.

Lets say it is initially filled with 1's and I'm trying to overwrite it with 0's.

```
(gdb) set $i = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int))

(gdb) set *$i = -1

(gdb) x/t $i

0x76d8550:  11111111111111111111111111111111
```

The data is not modified at all when I:

- Make a gdb.Value out of memset function pointer and call it in Python with the right address;
- Run ctypes' memset(), passing it the right address.

```
(gdb) pi memset = gdb.parse_and_eval("(void*(*)(void*,int,size_t))memset").dereference()

(gdb) pi str(memset)

'{void *(void *, int, size_t)} 0x7fffe992e760 <memset>'

(gdb) pi

>>> i = 0x76d8550

>>> memset(i,0,4)

<gdb.Value object at 0x7fdc5c0fbef0>

>>> gdb.execute("x/t $i")

0x76d8550:  11111111111111111111111111111111
```

```
>>> import ctypes

>>> ctypes.memset(i,0,4)

124618064

>>> gdb.execute("x/t $i")

0x76d8550:  11111111111111111111111111111111
```

The data is modified as expected when I:

- Evaluate a string with the complete memset() expression using gdb.parse_and_eval().

```
>>> gdb.parse_and_eval("(void*)memset({},0,4)".format(i))

<gdb.Value object at 0x7fdb9eef58b0>

>>> gdb.execute("x/t $i")

0x76d8550:  00000000000000000000000000000000
```

Any explanation on why the 1st two options aren't working?

Thanks

Comment: How is it related to C?

Comment: @0___________: Memset is a libc function.

Comment: The method via `ctypes` can't work, since here you're writing in the address space of gdb itself, and not your executable. But the method with the memset function pointer should work, and it does for me.

Comment: What platform are you on? Which libc are you using? If it's GLIBC,  does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51935047/50617

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the addresses you get printed you are *probably* running on Linux/x86_64, and *possibly* using GLIBC as your standard `C` library. If so ...

... `memset` is complicated.

First, there are two separate implementations of `memset` -- a minimal one in `ld-linux.so` and a full-function one inside `libc.so.6`.

Second, the full implementation in `libc.so.6` is a GNU IFUNC, which means that it doesn't *itself* write to memory, it just returns the address of the function that *should* be used to write to memory on a given processor.

Lastly, as sbssa commented, `ctype.memset()` can't possibly work, because that's a `memset` that is within the GDB itself, not the `memset` in the inferior (being debugged) process. By calling `ctypes.memset(i,0,4)` you are corrupting a random location within GDB. This could result in anything, starting from "no effect" (if the corrupted address was unused but valid) to having the expression immediately crash (if the "to be corrupted" address is invalid) to a random crash in GDB later (if that corrupted address is actually used by GDB for something).

---

Putting this all together:

```
#include <string.h>

int jj = -1;
int main()
{
  memset(&jj, 0, sizeof(jj)); return 0;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `gcc -g x.c`, and running under GDB on Fedora 38 `x86_64`:

```
gdb -q ./a.out
Reading symbols from ./a.out...
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x40112a: file x.c, line 6.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at x.c:6
6         memset(&jj, 0, sizeof(jj)); return 0;
Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install glibc-2.37-10.fc38.x86_64
(gdb) p &memset
$1 = (void (*)(void)) 0x7ffff7fec530 <memset>

(gdb) pi memset = gdb.parse_and_eval("(void*(*)(void*,int,size_t))memset").dereference()
(gdb) pi print(str(memset))
{void *(void *, int, size_t)} 0x7ffff7fec530 <memset>

(gdb) info sym 0x7ffff7fec530
memset in section .text of /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Here you can see that GDB got the *wrong* `memset` (the minimal implementation). It would still work, but is suboptimal and may have other restrictions -- it was never intended to be used outside of `ld-linux` itself. For example, it may assume that the buffer is 8-byte aligned, or that the size is at least 8 bytes, etc.

What about the *real* `memset` that is called in `main`?

```
(gdb) b memset
Breakpoint 2 at 0x7ffff7e7cf60 (2 locations)
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2.1, 0x00007ffff7e7cf60 in memset_ifunc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7e7cf60 in memset_ifunc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7fdac42 in elf_ifunc_invoke (addr=<optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-irel.h:32
#2  _dl_fixup (l=0x7ffff7ffe2d0, reloc_arg=<optimized out>) at dl-runtime.c:125
#3  0x00007ffff7fdcf3e in _dl_runtime_resolve_xsavec () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-trampoline.h:130
#4  0x000000000040113e in main () at x.c:6
```

Note that this is the IFUNC` I was talking about.

```
(gdb) fin
Run till exit from #0  0x00007ffff7e7cf60 in memset_ifunc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
0x00007ffff7fdac42 in _dl_fixup (l=0x7ffff7ffe2d0, reloc_arg=<optimized out>) at dl-runtime.c:125
125     dl-runtime.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) p/x $rax
$2 = 0x7ffff7f37950
(gdb) info sym 0x7ffff7f37950
__memset_avx2_unaligned in section .text of /lib64/libc.so.6
```

The `__memset_avx2_unaligned` is the *actual* `memset` implementation selected for *this* host (out of several possible; the other possibilities in this build of GLIBC are: `__memset_erms`, `__memset_avx2_unaligned_erms`, `__memset_evex_unaligned`, `__memset_evex_unaligned_erms`).

Note that even though we've already returned from "memset", the value of `jj` is still `-1`:

```
(gdb) x/t &jj
0x40400c <jj>:  11111111111111111111111111111111
(gdb) watch -l jj
Hardware watchpoint 3: -location jj
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Hardware watchpoint 3: -location jj

Old value = -1
New value = 0
0x00007ffff7f37ae4 in __memset_avx2_unaligned_erms () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

P.S. Why is the value changed by `__memset_avx2_unaligned_erms()` and not by `__memset_avx2_unaligned()` ?

Because the latter uses "tail call" to the latter:

```
(gdb) disas __memset_avx2_unaligned
Dump of assembler code for function __memset_avx2_unaligned:
   0x00007ffff7f37950 <+0>:     endbr64
   0x00007ffff7f37954 <+4>:     vmovd  %esi,%xmm0
   0x00007ffff7f37958 <+8>:     mov    %rdi,%rax
   0x00007ffff7f3795b <+11>:    cmp    $0x20,%rdx
   0x00007ffff7f3795f <+15>:    jb     0x7ffff7f37aa0 <__memset_avx2_unaligned_erms+224>
   0x00007ffff7f37965 <+21>:    vpbroadcastb %xmm0,%ymm0
   0x00007ffff7f3796a <+26>:    cmp    $0x40,%rdx
   0x00007ffff7f3796e <+30>:    ja     0x7ffff7f37a09 <__memset_avx2_unaligned_erms+73>
   0x00007ffff7f37974 <+36>:    vmovdqu %ymm0,-0x20(%rdi,%rdx,1)
   0x00007ffff7f3797a <+42>:    vmovdqu %ymm0,(%rdi)
   0x00007ffff7f3797e <+46>:    vzeroupper
   0x00007ffff7f37981 <+49>:    ret
```

Comment: Wow didn't expect a whole goddamn rabbit hole in there. Thanks so much for the detailed explanation.