# Conditional Breakpoint - VS community 2019

Tags: c++, conditional-breakpoint

I have been working on visual studio community 2019 and i ask you , how can i set a conditional breakpoint
to see when auxfp.Name is the Student "Nilza" !
Thank You guys.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsJCH.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsJCH.png): [image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdEhr.png

Comment: what's the problem with what you have already done? What datatype is `auxfp.Name`? please provide a [mre]

Comment: Sorry for the time, but auxfp.Name is a string !

Comment: a `std::string` a `const char*` something else? please provide a [mre]

Comment: is a std::string and i have a file .csv that i want to read and i need when the line that i'm reading (in a line i have to read a timestamp, name, num and 5 options that refer to a person ) have the std::String auxfp.Name == "Nilza" to stop the code and see what is happening !

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740858/how-to-create-conditional-breakpoint-with-stdstring