# How to use strcmp in MSVC C++ debugger when having array?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, conditional-breakpoint

I am trying to place a conditional breakpoint for a string comparison using `strcmp`. In the debug console, below command works

`(char*)b->vec.buf.ptr.pointer,[b->vec.len]`

However, when I want to use this in `strcmp` using below command,

`strcmp(((char*)b->vec.buf.ptr.pointer,[b->vec.len]), "test") == 0`

I get `Invalid format specifier.`. I think I am not able to use the `()` inside `strcmp`.

How to achieve this?

Comment: The debugger can't compile c++ code. Put the test in an appropriate place in the source, recompile, and use the debugger there. You can test one char at a time and combine them in the debugger. `*(char*)b->vec.buf.ptr.pointer == 't'`

Comment: Use `strncmp` instead if you don't have a 0 terminated string. `strncmp(((char*)b->vec.buf.ptr.pointer, "test", b->vec.len) == 0`

Comment: @doug Visual Studio can call some standard functions in the debugger. `strcmp` and `strncmp` work as well as others. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/expressions-in-the-debugger?view=vs-2022

Comment: @RetiredNinja  Cool. Didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: @doug -- I think the earlier versions of the debugger, back in the VS 2003 or 2005 days, the VS debugger had those issues you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @RetiredNinja. Since this is doing first n char, I could see it is returning true even if my second string is `testabc`. Can I give 2 different length?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't remember the version they added it in either. I thought maybe 2008, but this looks like it was probably 2010 or 2012. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15196867/920069 Sadly the linked article is dead. :(

Comment: You can use additional logic in the breakpoint if you need to, like `(b->vec.len == strlen("testabc")) && (strncmp(((char*)b->vec.buf.ptr.pointer, "testabc", b->vec.len) == 0)` At some point though your eyes start to hurt trying to write all that in the conditional box so you just add an `if (...) { int zzzz = 0; }` in the code and put the breakpoint inside the `if`. :)

Comment: Thanks @RetiredNinja. This logic might work. I am doing this on Rust and Rust compile time is not that quicker for big code

Comment: @RetiredNinja - Can you add this as your answer? I can mark it answered